# Kentico 10 Link to existing page feature

Tags: templates, repeater, kentico

Is there any way to force Kentico 10 to adopt a certain template when I link to another page with a template of a type I do not want?

An example would be I have a folder of CTA's. I want one of these CTA's to link to a page that uses the template "genericTemplate" but I would like the linked page I just created to be of template type "nonGenericTemplate".

The reason for this is that "genericTemplate" does not have the fields I am looking for and I would prefer to not force people to input field data in two places ("genericTemplate" and "nonGenericTemplate")

Answer (score 0):

I maybe misunderstanding what you mean by CTA; to me it's a link that a user can click on.

I don't believe that Kentico puts the field on the Page Template object, but on the Page Type object. The Page Type reflects what can be stored against a page, the Page Template reflects how the page looks.

When you create pages in Kentico you can assign a default Page Template to a Page Type in the administration interface; it's in the New document settings category of the Page Type interface called *Default page template*

If it's Page Type you meant, you can change the administration interface itself to only display fields when certain criteria are met. You could write a macro too, if the logic is quite complex. You can do this against a field itself or if you've got linked classes you can do it against the whole group. That way, you'd only need one Page Type to cover all eventualities.

John